# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when running testsuite

Tags: laravel, phpunit, homestead, laravel-5.5

I randomly (and often) receive a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error when running phpunit (version 6.4.1) on a testsuite inside ssh of homestead. When I run one unit test at a time or run a smaller suite, the tests all pass. The most memory any one of the tests use is 20.00 MB.

Outside ssh (PHPUnit version 6.2.3), the tests all run perfectly: `OK (131 tests, 1876 assertions)`

In each test, I use `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations`, running on a database connection:

```
'testing' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

Should I be concerned at all about this? Is it just best practice to run phpunit outside of ssh? I don't want to update my PHPUnit and then find that I have to run my tests one by one.

Comment: You complain about segmentation fault yet fail to provide enough details, how much RAM does your droplet have? What exact sqlite version you have? What does this have to do with SSH? Try to explain in more detail. If the main question is "should I be worried about this?" I think its really bad question if you are an engineer. Obvious answer is "Hell yes, you need to figure the problem out".

Comment: Kyslik, The issue really has to do with laravel/homestead. By "ssh", I mean that the problem only occurs when I ssh into the virtual box - and it runs perfectly outside of the virtual box on WIndows 10. It's in Laravel 5.5 running on Vagrant 1.9.7. I'm pretty sure that the question is crystal clear to Homestead users. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Go in to your box and do `sqlite3 --version`.

Comment: 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24 3d862f207e3adc00f78066799ac5a8c282430a5f

Comment: And whats your local sqlite3 version where it all works?

Comment: command not found. Would I have to switch from :memory to a db file and then check the header to get that information?